# How to change color of icons in Font Awesome 5?

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I can't colorize the Font Awesome 5 icons using these codes. I tried `fill` css property for setting color but it didn't work.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container mt200 icons">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="bggray2 text-center">
      <i class="fas fa-microphone fa-5x"></i>
      <div class="title">LOREM</div>
      <div class="text">Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="bggray2 text-center">
      <i class="far fa-edit fa-5x"></i>
      <div class="title">LOREM</div>
      <div class="text">Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.icons i {
  color: #2759AE;
}
```

Comment: the Version 5 has nothing to do with the Version 4 of font awesome. All the duplicates are irrelevant and the OP is already changing the color like it should be done in the V4 but it's not working.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Font Awesome 5 uses `svg` for icons and `path` inside are set with `fill:currentColor` so simply change color of `svg`:

```css
.icons svg {
 color:#2759AE;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="container mt200 icons">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="bggray2 text-center">
      <i class="fas fa-microphone fa-5x"></i>
      <div class="title">LOREM</div>
      <div class="text">Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="bggray2 text-center">
      <i class="far fa-edit fa-5x"></i>
      <div class="title">LOREM</div>
      <div class="text">Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the code, the `i` are replaced with `svg` when you load the JS version:

[image]

---

You can apply color to `i` in case you are using the CSS version.

```css
.icons i {
 color:#2759AE;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"><div class="container mt200 icons">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="bggray2 text-center">
      <i class="fas fa-microphone fa-5x"></i>
      <div class="title">LOREM</div>
      <div class="text">Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="bggray2 text-center">
      <i class="far fa-edit fa-5x"></i>
      <div class="title">LOREM</div>
      <div class="text">Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So to make sure it will work in all the cases simply use both selector:

```
.icons i,
.icons svg {
   color: #2759AE;
}
```

Comment: How do I change the color to be a gradient? CSS color property doesn't support gradients.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using the svg-with-js version of Font Awesome 5 it takes everything in the `<i></i>` and preprocesses it into an `<svg>`. It specifies that the path has `fill="currentColor"` So, you have to set `currentColor` to the colour you want somehow. One option is:

```
svg {color: blue;}
```

The [official docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#additional-styling) recommend inline style:

```
<i class="far fa-edit fa-5x" style="color:blue"></i>
```

Or, set `currentColor` in one of the outer elements. For example:

```
<div class="bggray2 text-center" style="color: blue;">
  <i class="far fa-edit fa-5x"></i>
</div>
```

And to move it to the CSS file, you could:

```
div .bggray2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 you can use and of the text-'color' settings in the parent of the  tag.

```
<div class="bggray2 text-danger">
 <i class="far fa-edit fa-5x"></i>
 </div>
```