# Fontawesome: Is there a way to maintain CSS from CSS with Webfonts implementation when changing to SVG Sprites?

Tags: css, svg, font-awesome

I am trying to switch to the SVG Sprites implementation for Fontawesome 5 from the CSS with Webfonts implementation (for security reasons). I want to maintain the default CSS. Is there a way to do this? Or will I have to manually style all of my icons when changing over?

Comment: What was your security concern?

Comment: (1) you will need to target SVG and no more i :https://stackoverflow.com/a/48608619/8620333 (2) you need to adjust the code if you are using pseudo element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48753896/8620333