# Transform scale slightly nudges Font Awesome icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-5

I have a Font Awesome icon inside a parent div with `display: flex` which itself is inside a container div that's `display: flex`.

When I try `transform: scale(1.2)` on hover it slightly nudges the element:

https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Knights/gptyo3be/5/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

i {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

i:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <i class="fa fa-eye" id="single-item-eye"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SVG version instead and you won't have the issue. Scaling an SVG is better than scaling a text:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

svg {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

svg:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <i class="fa fa-eye" id="single-item-eye"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Related: [Why is text getting blurry and wobbles during 2d scale transform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50913783/8620333)

Comment: It works in the fiddle but not on my website for some reason. Is there any other setup aside from linking the script tag?

Comment: make sure you remove the CSS and keep on the script

Comment: @Daniel_Knights also clear your cache, maybe you still see the old one

Comment: I've done that and it works like in your fiddle but now all the other fontawesome icons on my page don't work

Comment: @Daniel_Knights you are using pseudo element ?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: you are inserting some icon using ::before/::after?

Comment: Not directly, no

Comment: @Daniel_Knights also note that using the SVG mean that you no more have < i > but svg tag. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48753896/8620333 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/48608619/8620333