# Color Change for Font Awesome Icon Not Working

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have some font awesome icons that I want to change to a different color but for some reason it will not work. Here's my html and css:

HTML

```
<span><i class="fas fa-globe fa-5x change-color"></i></span>
```

CSS

```
.change-color {
       color: #3993e5 !important;
               }
```

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48608619/8620333

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
I just had to wrap the icon with a div

```
<span><div><i class="fas fa-globe fa-5x change-color"></i></div></span>
```

Comment: I fixed the issue.

Comment: adding the div fixed the issue though

Answer (score 0):

Will if you using the js file from FontAwosem you should know that this I HTML tag will be removed and replaced with SVG tag so all you need to do is say something like that in your CSS file

```
svg {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Be sure that your icon font-family is Font-awesome.

Comment: Link this to your head :
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

and btw your code is not fine :
you didn't use } to finish your css style

Comment: I do have the cdn in the head and I changed the ending tag and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your Icon doesn't need font awesome premium membership maybe?

Comment: Use font-size please

Comment: It doesn't need premium. I need to change the color, not the size. fa-5x is to change the size.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.change-color {
font-family:FontAwesome;
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a class="btn-cta-freequote" href="#">Get a FREE Quote <i class="fas fa-globe fa-5x change-color"></i></a>
```